# Can a Logic App AWS SQS Connector read messages from an SQS Message Queue?

Tags: amazon-sqs, azure-logic-apps

I need to read messages from an AWS SQS queue and push the results into an Azure Service Bus. I like Azure Logic Apps and they do have an SQS connector. If I implement this connector in a Logic App will I be able to read a message from the SQS Queue and send to the Service Bus in the Logic App? I wanted to ask if anyone has achieved this before I spent time in implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, This is achievable through Logic apps. You just need to have the connection settings (i.e.. The Access key Id, Access Key Secret and SQS URL) to connect your SQS to your Logic app.

Here is my Logic app
[image]

Message that I'm sending from SQS
[image]

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was hoping to hear.